# How can I toggle displaying data from SQL between 2 dates?

Tags: sql-server

I'm relatively new to SQL, so this may seem a bit of a trivial question, but I can't seem to pull the data I want.

The data I'm trying to get is for an announcements section on a homepage. I've got 'DateFrom' and 'DateTo' columns in my SQL table- and only want to display the announcement if today's date lands within those 2 date ranges (for example, if I had an announcement which has a DateFrom of 1/12/2015 and DateTo of 15/12/2015, it would not display).

My current SQL for the problem is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAnnouncements WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this ie, you need to skip the time part from your GETDATE() result so as to match the date column:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAnnouncements WHERE CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo;
```

*Assuming that the datatype for DateFrom and DateTo column is Date and the format of the date is in DD/MM/YYYY format.*